# Any good guide about iPhone Core Data?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data

I'm looking for some guide, I already looked at it a bit on cocoadev and in a book but I didn't find any good guide. I mean those guides were talking about multiple concepts at once so now I only want a simple straightforward guide about how to use it.

Anyone knows any good guide?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this one out:

**More iPhone 3 Development: Tackling iPhone SDK 3**

[http://www.amazon.com/More-iPhone-Development-Tackling-Beginning/dp/143022505X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022505X)

This book and the previous one are excellent. This latest book starts with a very straightforward and detailed tutorial about Core Data spanning several chapters and so far I'm liking it much more than Marcus Zarra's Core Data book.

Comment: Great! I never saw this book before :)

Comment: It's brand new. I preordered it and it was shipped around January 1st. I also recommend subscribing to Jeff L's blog and downloading the sample code from the book from his forum.

Answer (score 7):

Marcus Zarra has an excellent Core Data [book](http://pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/core-data) out from Pragmatic.

Answer (score 3):

I found Apple's [Core Data Tutorial for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good tutorial from [iPhone in Action](http://iphoneinaction.manning.com/iphone_in_action/core-data/) which I find a straightforward guide for Core Data uses.

1. How Core Data models its data.
2. How to get data out of Core Data.
3. How to put data into Core Data.
4. How to insert data in advance.

etc...

Comment: Thanks for the link! I haven't come across this site before, but it looks like a good resource to know about.

Comment: The website seems good, but the book looks very good too. But I can't find anything core data-related in the book.
Gotta check the site out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a more recent Marcus S. Zarra book about [CoreData](http://pragprog.com/book/mzcd2/core-data) from Pragmatic - which I prefer more than the one which Gottlieb offered even it named as 2nd edition it's a different writing - with full of excellent tricks and code samples with Zarra's unique and state of art coding style.

My second offer is [Pro Core Data for iOS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006C9ELKS) from Privat and Warner from Apress which is again an excellent choice with clear and concise style.