# Save and Load Data - CoreData

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, save, uidatepicker

I am new to CoreData and in my iPhone app I want to know how to save some text, then load it back in. But the trick is, loading it back in when the date in the UIDatePicker is the same as when I saved it, like a calendar.

### Update

Thanks for the replies, especially the for the code sample. However I have some issues understand how this fits together, forgive me. I want to learn how this works, but to get it working in the mean time will really be helpful.

Presumably I put your first code chunk in the did finish editing method (save when leaving text box) and then the second chunk in the date changed method (load when changing the date)?

This code, does this use the entity and property names? How exactly do I need to setup my xcdatamodel file? Do I need to use this code or does this just demonstrate what entities and properties I need?

```
DatedText{
    savedText:String
    dateSaved:Date
}
```

This line says 'mo' is undeclared: (FIXED)

```
    newDatedText=mo=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DateText"
inManagedObjectContext:theManagedObjectContext];
```

Presumably below 'someText' is the text I want save? And the 'aDateObject' is the date in my UIDatePicker?

```
[newDatedText setValue:someText forKey:@"savedText"];
    [newDatedText setValue:aDateObject forKey:@"dateSaved"];
```

Request for member 'moc' in something not a structure or union:

```
NSEntityDescription *testEntity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DatedText" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
```

Whats 'targetDate' (undeclared)? UIDatePicker date again?

```
NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateSaved==%@", targetDate];
```

Request for member 'moc' in something that's not a structure or a union:

```
NSArray *fetchedObjs=[self.moc executeFetchRequest:theFetch error:&fetchError];
```

Comment: The `newDatedText=mo=` was a typo in my answer. Now corrected.

Comment: Ok, thought it may have been. But Im still not understanding a few thing: http://b.imagehost.org/0718/Screen_shot_2010-11-17_at_22_59_14.png

Comment: You keep trying to copy and paste example code directly into you project. This is will not work. We don't have access to your project and therefore cannot create variable names that match those that you have assigned. We just have to use made up names like `DatedText`or `targetDate`. You are supposed to change the made up variable names to the ones that will match your project.

Comment: Oh I understand that, apologies, I was just trying to work out what they were representing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start you need a data model to reflect what you want to save, in this case, some text and a date. So:

```
DatedText{
    savedText:String
    dateSaved:Date
}
```

To create a new `DatedText` object (without a custom class) do:

```
NSManagedObject *newDatedText;
newDatedText=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DateText" inManagedObjectContext:theManagedObjectContext];
[newDatedText setValue:someText forKey:@"savedText"];
[newDatedText setValue:aDateObject forKey:@"dateSaved"];

NSError *saveError=nil;
[theManagedObjectContext save:&saveError];
if (saveError!=nil) {
    NSLog(@"[%@ saveContext] Error saving context: Error=%@,details=%@",[self class], saveError,saveError.userInfo);
}
```

To retrieve a `DatedText` object with a specific date you create a fetch like so:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *testEntity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DatedText" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
[fetch setEntity:testEntity]; 
NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateSaved==%@", targetDate];
[fetch setPredicate:[NSArray arrayWithObject:pred]];

NSError *fetchError=nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjs=[theManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:theFetch error:&fetchError];
if (fetchError!=nil) {
    NSLog(@" fetchError=%@,details=%@",fetchError,fetchError.userInfo);
    return nil;
}
```

`fetchedObjs` will now contain an array of all `DatedText` objects with the same `savedDate` as `targetDate`.

Comment: Thanks for the response and great code sample! I am having a few issues and edited my original post, could you take a look please?

Comment: Having spent so much time looking at different code and paying with it its making much more sense coming back to this, however one thing about the managed object context. Where does it come from? Do I just need to declare one? Or is it more complex? And 'theFetch' is that not just what you declared as 'fetch'?

Comment: Use one of the Xcode template projects to create a core data based app. In the application delegate class, it will provide methods that will show you how you set up the core data stack.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of resources about Core Data, you could follow the following links to learn it.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html Core Data Tutorial for iOS: this is really great, official document, easy to learn, with downloadable source.
[Any good guide about iPhone Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054376/any-good-guide-about-iphone-core-data) Someone asked the same question before, you can take a look.

Comment: This is the problem with giving links instead of code sample. First link already broken.