# Help with core database education

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I am new to Objective C as well as programing all together.  So any and all help is very appreciated!  I am trying to build an app that will need a database.  All of the references that I have read on the issue of core database warns against noobs diving in.  So far everything that I have read gives me pieces and parts.  Can you recommend a great summary reference that could walk someone like me through the creation and development of such a database.  The database that I am interested in creating will store customer preferences.  So I want to be able to input, retrieve and ultimately update the stored data.  Thank you in advance for taking the time to read my query and a special thanks to those who have taken the time to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great book on Core Data itself that is geared towards desktop and iphone applications, but it requires a decent working knowledge of objective-c/cocoa touch imo: [Prag Core Data](http://pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/core-data).  Another fair read is the Apple documentation on the subject.  and there are some pretty good questions/answers here on stack overflow regarding the subject.  And as you said, there are scattered tutorials outlining specific things all over the internet and on some popular iphone/objective-c blogs.

This being said, if you are a beginner to programming in general, I would suggest that Core Data/databases in general (SQL etc) might be a bit of an advanced topic to begin on.

Comment: I would add that both Apple and Pragmatic Programmers (pragprog.com) have sample code as well. This can be useful, in that it will let you see a running app and its source code. All the same, I concur with Jesse that you may be jumping in to the deep end prematurely.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I will check it out.  I do have one followup question.  I don't mean to be disrespectful and I understand that if it were easy that everyone would do it, but what makes it so hard?  Is just understanding the language or more of a conceptual issue?

Comment: Its a conceptual issue for most people..and there are a lot of very small nuances that trip up even experienced database people.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of similar post already discussed in SO.

For Ex. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860886/coredata-book-recommendation) , [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054376/any-good-guide-about-iphone-core-data)

Answer (score 0):

SO if you are talking about the core database concepts then you should clear with the databases , what i mean is you should know how to , where to and when to use database in a system. It is not all the time necessary but it is important to know these things 
to know more about it plz follow the link below
[Click here to learn Database and DB Designing](http://www.edupotpie.com/courses/Learn-Database-and-DB-Designing/3/20/What-is-Microsoft-Access/980/Introduction-to-Database.html)